# Merge fields Bold Word 2010

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

How can we make all merge fields bold in Microsoft Word 2010? Please suggest a method using VBA. Also, merge fields appearing within if conditions must also be made bold.

Answer (score 0):

You can record a macro using find and replace. Use `^d` to find all field and replace with the same text using `^&` and set the format to Bold. Before recording, toggle all field codes by selecting all and using <kbd>Shift + F9</kbd>. Recording this process yields the following VBA code:

```
Sub MergeBold()
'
' MergeBold Macro
'
'
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Fields.ToggleShowCodes
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^d"
        .Replacement.Text = "^&"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Fields.ToggleShowCodes
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
End Sub
```